# Ajax request to the site which has asynchronous data loading

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to pick up HTML pages, to parse them and pull email of company out of them. But emails on the HTML pages load asynchronously and i GET only "..." data instead of emails by ajax request. How i can wait untill emails will be fully loaded and only after that to finish my request to site? Thanks

```
     names=['name1', 'name2']; //example of site names
     names.map(name=>{
      let url='https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://companies.dev.by/'+name;  //CORS bypass 
      $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "text",
        success : function(company){
          let companyDoc = parser.parseFromString(company, "text/html");  //company is without loaded email, only '...'
          let row = document.createElement('tr');
          let td1 = document.createElement('td');
          td1.innerHTML = companyDoc.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML;
          row.appendChild(td1);
          document.getElementById('body').appendChild(row);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    })
```

Comment: Cant you access the backend directly from which the emails are loaded?

Comment: @Aaron, in the source panel Chrome i see only bundles, it is hard to understand smth

Comment: I recommend you use [PhantomJs](https://phantomjs.org/). It is a headless browser that allows you to run the site javascript and thus render the emails.

Comment: What is he asking here? Does he want the map method to wait until the current ajax process is done and only proceed to next afterwards ?

Comment: @RashadKokash looks good! Thank. I will try it

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin no, when i do request to the site, in the response i get the page with no loaded data which is loaded by the site asynchronously too. In the result my ajax pequest finished. And only after several seconds the data arrived in the site, but i don`t see it

Comment: @diesel94, Ok then try adding "load" event listener to the document returned from the DOM parser, and inside the handler process the site

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin i have tried to use `companyDoc.onload = () =>{_code_}` but the code is not work generally